# customize default search results shown on SharePoint Online Top Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

When you click on the default search box available at top of SharePoint Site, you see some default results shown by SharePoint.
I want to know the feature that enables/disables this behaviour.
And can we customize it further.

[the bahavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNVgf.png)

I tried going through the Search settings of site collection and Central admin.
No luck.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187573/avoid-default-results-in-search-result-web-part

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread for you that has the same need as yours:[Avoid default results in Search Result Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187573/avoid-default-results-in-search-result-web-part)

He solved the problem by adding `\\{searchboxquery?}` to the Search Results Web Parts content source, maybe it's worth a try for you.